# Java CipherInputStream using AES/GCM encryption wont read until close

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, inputstream

I need an encrypted in/output stream for my sockets. I have tried just about everything out there to fix this with no luck. I know the socket will receive the data once the socket or output stream are closed. However this is not useful what so ever. I would love any input on this.

"*This is not a duplicate, there are other questions about this subject, however none provide an answer to this.*"

**For anyone that is struggling with this same issue I made a custom cipher stream and added DataInputStream / DataOutputStream to it. It will work fine with GCM with some minor tweaks.**

https://gist.github.com/DrBrad/0148f54cb1e5f5b04414c7756b97996a

```
public static void testC()throws Exception {

    String password = "PASSWORD";

    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7000);

    CipherInputStream in = new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), getEN(password, true));
    CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), getEN(password, false));

    out.write("HELLO WORLD".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

public static void testS(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private Socket socket;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7000);
                String password = "PASSWORD";

                System.out.println("STARTED");

                while((socket = serverSocket.accept()) != null){
                    CipherInputStream in = new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), getEN(password, true));
                    CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), getEN(password, false));

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                    int length = in.read(buffer);

                    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, length));

                    socket.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }).start();
}


public static Cipher getEN(String password, boolean t)throws Exception {
    byte[] salt = new byte[8], iv = new byte[16];

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
    if(t){
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, spec);
    }else{
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, spec);
    }

    return cipher;
}
```

Comment: Just checking-- is there a reason you're not using SSL/TLS to secure the connection?

Comment: Yes haha, otherwise I would use it

Comment: Looks like this code is using a fixed IV of all zeroes. That's.... really weak (unless you're using a different password/key for each connection). See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26790/how-bad-it-is-using-the-same-iv-twice-with-aes-gcm

Comment: Use an unpredictable IV/nonce, make the nonce 12 bytes not 16, use an unpredictable salt, use a proper read loop...

Comment: Explain why you need to decrypt the cipher before you receive and check the authentication tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CipherOutputStream is not suitable for this kind of use, because of how its [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html#flush()) method behaves. It only flushes data up to a complete cipher block boundary. If the length of the message you're sending is not an exact multiple of the cipher block length, some of the data is going to stay in the stream's buffer until you write more data or close the stream. Closing the stream pads the final input so it aligns to a block boundary.

This limitation is reasonable, since block ciphers operate on one block of data at a time.

Comment: Any recommendations on alternative solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you could manually add some message framing and padding so your message length is a multiple of the block size (for AES, that's 16 bytes), and flush the output stream after writing each message?

Comment: Counter modes should solve the problem, AES GCM being an example.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk OP is already using AES/GCM. Can you elaborate please on why using a counter mode would make a difference?

Comment: Counter mode has no block size requirements, it essentially turns a block cipher into a stream cipher, encrypting/decrypting one byte at a time. It's unclear which statement OP is having trouble with since his example doesn't show much.

Comment: There is no error, I felt the issue was quite clear. The issue is the output stream must be closed in order for the input to receive the bytes. This however is not useful what so ever for sockets. Cipher Streams seem to not work for sockets no matter the version of AES, however I'm using GCM.

Comment: @TheAnarch: `...Cipher Streams seem to not work for sockets...` and such a general statement is simply false.

Comment: If this is the case then I will have to make my own stream, do you know if I need to create a new cipher per message?